# subset a matrix by a expression with a column name

Tags: r, matrix, subset

`data<- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow=3)`

`colnames(data) <- c("a", "b", "c")`

How can we achieve the following for a matrix when the columnname (b) must be in the expression?
subset(data, b > 5)

Converting the matrix into a data.frame would work. But I am looking for a solution specifically for a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `subset` with a matrix with names because columns are not stored as separate objects. A matrix is all just one vector with an extra dimension attribute. You would need to more explicit indexing. This will work

```
data[data[,"b"]>5,]
```

If you look at the `subset.matrix` function you can see it's just a wrapper to the `[,]` indexing operation. If you need the symbol `b` to work, you'd need to do the extra work to subset the data which is basically doing the same work as converting the data to a data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
> data[data[, deparse(quote(b))] > 5, , drop = FALSE]
     a b c
[1,] 3 6 9
```

or

```
> subset.matrix(data, data[, deparse(quote(b))] > 5)
     a b c
[1,] 3 6 9
```

---

## Note:

I would say, it is POSSIBLE to make it as what you asked for, but it would not be as simple as `data[data[,"b"]>5,]` for matrix `data`.